# A step-by-step debugger in C++ win32 projects in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

When I would work on *C++ Win32 console applications* I would use of *F11* for *step into* and *F10* for *step over* in debugger (*DEBUG* tab of visual studio, say 2012). But now there function keys don't work as they should in *C++ win32 projects*. Is there any else method for following code lines in practice in *win32 projects* like the work that *F10* and *F11* would do in *win32 console applications*?

Comment: Firstly, stepping through the source requires debug symbols, maybe you switched to release mode? Then, as Friedrich suggests, it would be interesting to know if only the keys stopped working or if you can still step using the buttons on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

There are buttons for such kind of things in th IDE and it seems really strange that the function keys should not work any longer....

Comment: The function keys are F10 and F11 as have been mentioned in Debug tab and as I said they don't work well in win32 projects. By well I mean they don't track the code lines and the output window from beginning until end like in win32 console applications.

Comment: A potential issue is that windows programs respond to a stream of messages one at a time, so you may need to click on a source line and select "run to cursor" (or set breakpoints) at the entry points of functions you want to step through.

Comment: @rcgdr: I went to the _main()_ function (where all operations begin) and right-click and _run to curso_ then used F10 and F11 as for previous one. It worked. Thanks. You may want to put that solution into an _Answer_ so that I can give you votes! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also check the settings in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.